# Python only running first line, not sure what I'm missing

Tags: python

I just started learning today and I'm writing a simple block. It asks for the name and then stops. This is what I get http://imgur.com/KTwQz6G but only if I paste from IDLE. If I copy it from this site it seems to work. Maybe it's because I'm using an old version of IDLE to write it?

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")

color = raw_input("What is your favorite color? ")

print "Well, Hello %s. I was hoping you would pick dark brown, 
but %s is cool too." % (name, color)
```

Comment: What is the problem? It is running fine for me.

Comment: You need to enter the name for the program to continue, right?

Comment: raw_input blocks execution of code until you input something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program will not ask all the questions at once. You need to enter a name when you are prompted to do so by the [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) method and then the same for color. Example:

```
>>>python file.py
What is your name? somename               #you type somename and press enter
What is your favorite color? somecolor    #you type somecolor and press enter
Well, Hello somename. I was hoping you would pick dark brown, but somecolor is cool too.
```

Answer (score 1):

It asks for the name. The user has to type it in the prompt then press enter in order for the code to continue executing. That's what raw_input does.